# Newline/linebreak in \message

Tags: tex-core, line-breaking

I want to prompt some messages to my console. I used

```
\message{Hi out there!}
```

Now i want some more Text but with an linebreak.

```
\message{Hello World %some line break here 
Salut monde
}
```

Well i scanned the TeXbook for and tried many things but without result. I would welcome any (related) comments.

BTW I want that to work with pdf(la)tex as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could set a value to `\newlinechar` representing the character which should cause the line break.

This works for me, printing out a line break after *Hello World* :

```
\newlinechar=`\^^J
\message{Hello World^^JSalut monde}
```

Comment: Do you even need the \newlinechar setting by default? But it's good to know how to set it explicitly.

Comment: @Will: without the setting, TeX printed `Hello World^^JSalut monde`, when I tested it. But pdfTeX doesn't require it - it breaks the line even without that setting.

Comment: Try `\showthe\newlinechar`. With pdflatex this should show 10, the character code of `^^J`. With e.g. pdftex, this gives -1, i.e. no new-line character.