# hyperref : break long lines in pdftitle and other fields

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking

I have a problem with hyperref:  how to break long lines in pdf fields : the pdftitle is very long and I want hyperref to begin a new line, just like it does for key-words.

I compile with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}


%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}


%%%% \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{czech}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdfencoding=auto,
psdextra,
}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={\today Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
}

\begin{document}
\today








\end{document}
```

Comment: My version of Acrobat only has enough room for one line of title, but several lines of keywords.  Any line breaking is done by the browser. not the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF format does not support explicit line breaks in PDF information fields.

`\textLF` (line feed) or `\textCR` (carriage return) could be tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Hello\textLF World},
  pdfsubject={Hello\textCR World},
}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

And evince shows indeed line breaks. **But** AR shows only the first line and the rest of the title or subject is not displayed. Therefore this method is not recommended.

Comment: summatra shows the LF and CR indeed, but not foxit....

Comment: `^^J` seems to behave similar to `\textCR`, learned this weird combination from e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6531/292673). Also `\textLF` seems not working.

Comment: @moudrick It depends on the PDF viewer, whether and which line breaks are supported.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the point, using

```
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={\today Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
pdfkeywords={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
}
```

the corresponding object in the PDF is

```
15 0 obj
<<
/Author()/Title(January\0404,\0402016Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit.)/Subject()/Creator(LaTeX with hyperref package)/Producer(LuaTeX-0.80.0)/Keywords(Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit\040Lorem\040ipsum\040dolor\040sit\040amet,\040consectetur\040adipiscing\040elit.)
/CreationDate (D:20160104115430-06'00')/ModDate (D:20160104115430-06'00')/Trapped/False/PTEX.Fullbanner (This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 5238))>>
endobj
```

The title and keywords are stored precisely the same.